# For what values of $m$, will the polynomial $P(x)=x^4+(m-3)x+m^2$ have four distinct real roots?

Tags: polynomials

I'm not quite too sure how to approach this question, so any explanation using any technique would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Graph! This is the simplest technique if you are asking for any technique.

Comment: If I want to understand the technique behind approaching these questions, how would I approach it algebraically then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume it has 4 real roots $a,b,c,d$. By vieta's formulas,

$$abcd=m^2$$
$$a+b+c+d=0$$
$$ab+bc+cd+da+ac+bd=0$$
$$abc+bcd+cda+dab=m-3$$

But since $(a+b+c+d)^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2+2(ab+bc+cd+da+ac+bd)$,

$$a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=0\implies a=b=c=d=0$$

So this means if $P(x)$ has all real roots they must be all $0$, contradicting distinctness.

Therefore no value of $m$ makes $P(x)$ have 4 distinct real roots.

Comment: This is great. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  it cannot have $\,4\,$ distinct real roots. Either use [Descartes' rule of signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs), or look at $\,P''(x)\,$.